# node.js use modules without assigning them to variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

In node.js, I have to put a stem in front of my module before I can call anything in it:

```
const example = require('example.js');
example.func();
```

I have a really messy node.js file and I would like to break it up into several pieces. However, my code looks something like this:

```
function func1(){ /* ... */ }
function func2(){ /* ... */ }

//blah blah
func1();
//blah blah    
func2();
```

If I split this up into file1.js and file2.js, my code would need to look like this:

```
var file1 = require('file1.js');
var file2 = require('file2.js');

//blah blah
file1.func1();
//blah blah
file2.func2();
```

I have to put file1 or file2 before my function to call it, which is something I would like to avoid. Is it possible to not have these stems?

***Clarification***
I want multiple functions per file. The example just uses 1 function per file as an example.

Comment: well, you could in file1.js have code like `global.func1 = function() { /* ... */ }` - but that's prone to all sorts of issues using `global` like that in a module

Comment: You can do `require('file1.js').func1()` - is this what you mean?

Comment: @pguardiario no I want to just write func1

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want each export to export just the function, rather than an object containing the function. In `file1` and `file2`, do:

```
module.exports = function func1() {
};
```

instead of

```
module.exports.func1 = function func1() {
};
```

And then you can call the functions like:

```
var func1 = require('file1.js');
var func2 = require('file2.js');

//blah blah
func1();
//blah blah
func2();
```

(it would probably make sense to rename the filenames to `func1.js` and `func2.js` as well)

Comment: Sorry for not putting this, but I want more than 1 function per file. This solution is still really helpful since I can at least split up my code now.